# Mapping a structure to uint64_t

Tags: c++

What is the right way to convert the structure below to `uint64_t`?

```
struct Data
{
    uint64_t sign : 1;
    uint64_t exp : 4;
    uint64_t man : 8;
};

static_assert(sizeof(Data) == sizeof(uint64_t));
```

the obvious one is

```
Data data;
uint64_t n = *(reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(&data));
```

but it does not compile as `constexpr` and produces the following warnings in GCC:

```
dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
```

**EDIT1:**

The value of resulting `uint64_t` may be different with different compilers. But the value of Data structure should be the same when I convert it back from `uint64_t`.

So, saying more exactly I need:

```
Data data;
uint64_t n = convert(data);
Data data2 = convert_back(n);
static_assert(data == data2);
```

Comment: 1+4+8 --> 13.  Dmitriano, `static_assert(sizeof(Data) == sizeof(uint64_t));` is readily false as `sizeof(Data)` could well be 2.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica changed `int`->`uint`. It was a typo.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `sizeof(Data)` can't be 2, it has to be 8, since the underlying type is 64bit, just only 13 bits are being assigned meaning.

Comment: @RemyLebeaum Hmmm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) the structure to an `uint64_t`. `std::memcpy` is a legal way to perform type punning, it is allowed since your structure is trivially-copyable.

---

In C++20 there is also [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast).

Unlike `std::memcpy` it's `constexpr`, but to make it work at compile-time I had to add `uint64_t : 51;` at the end of the struct.

Interestingly, Clang (unlike GCC and MSVC) [refused to perform it at compile-time](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Cbit%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%0Astruct+Data%0A%7B%0A++++uint64_t+sign+:+1%3B%0A++++uint64_t+exp+:+4%3B%0A++++uint64_t+man+:+8%3B%0A++++uint64_t+:+51%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++constexpr+Data+data%7B1,2,3%7D%3B%0A++++constexpr+auto+x+%3D+std::bit_cast%3Cstd::uint64_t%3E(data)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1201,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+12.0.1+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+12.0.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4):

```
note: constexpr bit_cast involving bit-field is not yet supported
```

Comment: `std::memcpy` requires `reinterpret_cast`, right?

Comment: @Dmitriano No, since it receives `void *`. A cast to `char *` would've been legal though, since `char` pointers are except from strict aliasing.

Comment: `std::memcpy` is not `constexpr`

Comment: @Dmitriano Yes. But a sane compiler can optimize it away and/or perform it at compile-time.

Comment: @Dmitriano If you want constexpr-ness, there is `std::bitcast`. See edit.

Answer (score 5):

The conversion is not "obvious" because the exact layout of `Data` is implementation defined (see [bit field](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field)). Moreover, your cast via pointers breaks strict aliasing, as the error suggests. There is no `uint64_t` stored at the adress of `data`.

You can convert it like this:

```
constexpr uint64_t Data_2_uint(const Data& d){
    return d.sign + (d.exp << 1) + (d.man << 5);
}
```

Comment: Yes, looks like `sizeof(Data)` is also implementation defined.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an implicit conversion, you may use union to access the same data structure with a different alias

```
union Data {
    struct {
        uint64_t sign : 1;
        uint64_t exp : 4;
        uint64_t man : 8;
    }
    uint64_t data_as_uint64;
}
```

To make sure you don't have memory representation problems with padding of the fields, you should use `#pragma pack`, and set the packing to 1

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
union Data {
    struct {
        uint64_t sign : 1;
        uint64_t exp : 4;
        uint64_t man : 8;
    }
    uint64_t data_as_uint64;
}
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Notice that `#pragma pack` is compiler dependent, and you need to make sure your compiler supports it.

Comment: Some compiler allow type punning via union as an extension but technically it is undefined behaivor to access the non active memebr of a union

Comment: `#pragma pack` looks like a C++ compiler extension and not part of C++.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You are correct, but most popular compilers support it - `msvc`, `gcc` and `clang`